# 1-liner for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this 1-liner:

```
python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print json.dumps(obj.get("dependencies"), indent=0, sort_keys=True)' < package.json
```

And I would like to find a nice, short solution instead of repeating myself, to do the print looping over `["dependencies", "devDependencies", "peerDependencies"]`.

The trivial, but not nice solution I have now:

```
python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print json.dumps(obj.get("dependencies"), indent=0, sort_keys=True);print json.dumps(obj.get("devDependencies"), indent=0, sort_keys=True);print json.dumps(obj.get("peerDependencies"), indent=0, sort_keys=True)' < package.json
```

I also tried things similar to:

```
python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);[print json.dumps(obj.get(dep), indent=0, sort_keys=True) for dep in "dependencies","devDependencies","peerDependencies"]' < package.json
```

UPDATE:

My goal is to get all the dependencies that have "git" in their url:

Input: package.json:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "dependencies": {
    "a": "git:aa",
    "b": "git:bb",
    "c": "cc"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "p": "git:pp"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "d": "git:dd"
  },
  "moo": "poo"
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
"a": "git:aa",
"b": "git:bb",
"c": "cc"
} {
"p": "git:pp"
} {
"d": "git:dd"
}
```

In fact I don't care much about the "}"-s and "{"-s, because I'll continue the 1-liner with: `| grep 'git:'`

Comment: Can you show us what you expect as output?

Comment: Separating the lines w/ semicolons instead of newlines doesn't really make it a 1-liner.

Comment: What issue(s) did you have with what you tried?  Please be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for `join`:

```
import json,sys
obj=json.load(sys.stdin)
print ' '.join(json.dumps(obj.get(dep), indent=0, sort_keys=True) for dep in ("dependencies", "devDependencies", "peerDependencies"))
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not a 1-liner, that's just you making your life harder. Your 1-liner can be as simple as:

```
python my-script.py
```

And have a nice formatted code inside a text file that doesn't goes against the entire spirit of the language: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Now about your problem:

```
import json, sys

deps = ["dependencies", "peerDependencies", "devDependencies"]
data = json.loads(sys.stdin)

for dep in deps:
    if data[dep].startswith("git:"):
        print data[dep]
```

I think that should do it, and then you don't need to `| grep` the output. 
Note that this is filtering dependencies that START with `git:`, NOT the ones that CONTAINS it as you requested, because i figured out that's what you want. Otherwise, you can replace the `if data[dep].startswith("git:")` by `if "git:" in data[dep]` and that would do it.